# sp_oauth.get_access_token(code) is retruning the same token for different users

Tags: oauth-2.0, spotipy

I am working on a personal project.
I am using `sp_oauth.get_access_token(authorization_code)` to get access token for the account.
The correct token was returned for the first user I tried, hence giving me the account info for that user. But when I tried a different account, with its unique code, `sp_oauth.get_access_token(authorization_code)` I am recieving the access token and hence account info of the first account.

I tried to use the `spotipy.util` to streamline the token access process, but it is also tricky becuase one of the parameters is username, which some users dont know by hard.